# How can I use Namespaces and USE function in magento 1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9, php, oop

**How can I use Namespaces and USE function in magento 1.9 ?**
I dont want to use require or include function just set one namespaces and use this in my controller like laravel or magento 2.
Is it possible in magento 1.9.

Comment: You want to use namespace of what ? please explain exactly what you want to do

Comment: For example : Assume I have create one php file and set namespace for this file and I want to use this file without using php require and include method I want to use this file in another file with USE function like we are using in laravel. Hope you got my point.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `_forward()` method like this:

```
$this->_forward($action = 'methodName', $controller = 'controller_name', $module = 'Modulename', $params = array('id'=>$id))
```

**But** it's not a **best way** and a **good practice**, I suggest you to create your function in a `helper` and call this function from a helper to the both controllers !